Error en com.google.android.gms
Desde hace poco tiempo me esta saliendo en una dos app de un mismo proyecto este error, aunque la app parece que funciona bien, no se si en un futuro habra problemas:
Ya llevo varias semanas con este tema y me empiezo a desesperar.
He leido que hay que pasar el proyecto a androidx pero al Migralo me dice : "No Usages  Found in the Proyect".
¿Como puedo solucionar este problema ?. Gracias.
Este es el error que me sale al ejecutarlo, aunque como he dicho si no fuese por el, error funciona bien presumiblemente.
E/GoogleApiManager: Failed to get service from broker. 
java.lang.SecurityException: Unknown calling package name 'com.google.android.gms'.
    at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3069)
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3053)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3036)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2978)
    at anag.a(:com.google.android.gms@244233029@24.42.33 (190400-689790151):36)
    at amyn.z(:com.google.android.gms@244233029@24.42.33 (190400-689790151):143)
    at amfs.run(:com.google.android.gms@244233029@24.42.33 (190400-689790151):54)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at bsep.mx(:com.google.android.gms@244233029@24.42.33 (190400-689790151):1)
    at bsep.dispatchMessage(:com.google.android.gms@244233029@24.42.33 (190400-689790151):5)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)

El buil.gradle (Modules....) tiene: (tambien lo que probado con             targetSdk 35, y sigue igual)
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'}

android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.valhondo.delgado.porrainfantil"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.3')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.4.4'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:8.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:20.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}

y el El buil.gradle (Project....) es asi:
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
        google()
        jcenter()

    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir}


Te sugiero agregar tu Manifest.xml también

No olvides que es importante agregar la dependencia de Google Play Services:
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:19.0.0'

Agrega esta dependencia y obviamente necesitas permiso de internet definido en tu AndroidManifest.xml.

En el Manifest.xml si tengo  el ,permiso de internet:     Pero al poner     implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:19.0.0' en el build gradle y sincronizarlo sale este error: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services:19.0.0
Add Google Maven repository and sync project
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: adminporrasci

En el Manifest.xml si tengo el ,permiso de internet:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Pero al poner
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:19.0.0'

en el build gradle y sincronizarlo sale este error:
Add Google Maven repository and sync project
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: adminporrasci

